# why int a= 4i; not report an syntax error(c++)

Tags: c++

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int a = 232u;
    int b = 4i;
    cout << a << endl << b;
}
```

I was review basic of cpp, As the screen shot I took, I tried to sign an unsigned int to a int which was fine, then I tried change that u to i and waiting for a error, but there's no error and output was 0. There's no define of i. So what happened.

I'm using xcode on mac, last picture is the build settings.

Comment: What development environment / compiler do you use? Are you sure that you don't get an error? Only thing I can think of is your IDE executing an old version of the executable for some reason.

Comment: No repro with gcc and clang. What compiler are you using?

Comment: it's Apple LLVM 8.0(default in xcode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ has a concept of literals, this is used to describe the type of a value. For example, [integer literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) can be used to write I want a integer `1` with a type `unsigned int`. We will write it `1u`.

In your case, your are probably using a [GNU extension for imaginary constants](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc//Complex.html). What you write don't compile in C++ standard.

The good way to use complex literal in C++ standard is to include include [`<complex>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex). And to use [`std::complex_literals`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i), this is only possible in C++14.

Comment: Maybe that's right, although I didn't include <complex> manual. But I tried other letters lake p and q it will report an error.

Answer (score 1):

The suffix `i` denotes the imaginary part of a complex number; when assigning an (implicitly) constructed complex number to integral value, only the real part is taken.

Hence, the following expression yields `0`:

```
int b = 4i;  // gives 0; real-part of 4i is 0, imaginary-part is 4: casting to int gives the real part, i.e. 0
```

But:

```
int x = 4i*4i; // gives -16; as i means the square root of -1, i*i yields -1; so 4i*4i = -16
```

Note that this works even without including `<complex>`.

Comment: That's exciting! I don't know why, but I feel exciting.

Comment: I like the extra example of `4i*4i` here.  I'm shocked that this works without the `<complex>` header, but obviously somebody is encountering it.